How to toggle a DropdownMenu in a ComposeView from a XML Button in the Activity?
I am currently migrating my XML layouts to Jetpack Compose.
I have developed a common androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu Compose function that I wish to employ anywhere in my current Android project and display (expand) it on the click of an XML Button.
This is my current code, which does work as desired. However I am unsure whether this is the best/correct approach.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.showDropDown)

        val showDropDownMenu = mutableStateOf(true)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            showDropDownMenu.value = true
        }

        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeDropDownMenuOuter).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                DropDownMenuUi(showDropDownMenu)
            }
        }
    }


The DropDownMenuUi Composable resembles this:
    @Composable
    fun DropDownMenuUi(showDropDownMenu: MutableState<Boolean>) {
        val expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(showDropDownMenu) }
        DropdownMenu(
           modifier = ddm.modifier ?: Modifier.padding(start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp),
           expanded = expanded.value,
           onDismissRequest = { expanded.value = false },
           offset = ddm.offset ?: DpOffset(0.dp, 0.dp)
        ) {
           ...
           ...
           ...
           ...
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...


my main concern is using val showDropDownMenu = mutableStateOf(true), is this ok for compose?
is there a more "compose" approach i could employ?

While the code works, it is redundant to create a mutableStateOf() in your Composable from the mutableStateOf() in your Activity. Also, it is not recommended to directly overwrite a MutableState from a nested Composable. Instead, your Composable should have a callback.
Another recent shift is that we should prefer MutableStateFlow (from Kotlin library) over mutableStateOf (from Compose library) when we are not in a Composable scope. By doing so, we decouple ViewModel or Activity code from Composable libraries. You then can collect a MutableStateFlow in your Composable using collectAsStateWithLifecycle().
Please try to refactor your DropDownMenuUi Composable like this:
@Composable
fun DropDownMenuUi(showDropDownMenu: Boolean, onDismiss: () -> Unit) {
    DropdownMenu(
        //...
        expanded = showDropDownMenu,
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        // ...
    ) {
        //...
    }
}

Then, in your onCreate function, declare a MutableStateFlow like this:
val showDropDownMenuState = MutableStateFlow(true)
button.setOnClickListener {
    showDropDownMenuState.value = true
}

Finally, invoke your Composable as follows:
setContent {

    // use below variable for reading the showDropDownMenuState
    val showDropDownMenu by showDropDownMenuState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    DropDownMenuUi(
        showDropDownMenu = showDropDownMenu,
        onDismiss = {
            showDropDownMenuState.value = false
        }
    )
}

